# (Basic) Get order number of an Object in Array - Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i have a basic question about Javascript ES6, Hope your helps!
I want to get order number of an Object in Array:

```
[
  { "pk": 23, "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/users/1/2_27.jpg"},
  { "pk": 11, "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/users/1/2_27.jpg"},
  { "pk": 67, "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/users/1/2_27.jpg"}
]
```

I have params.id: 11, I want to print **order_object = 2**

Comment: Did you mean the order of the element in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `findIndex`

```
var order_object = arr.findIndex( s => s.pk == 11 ) + 1;
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr  = [
  { "pk": 23, "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/users/1/2_27.jpg"},
  { "pk": 11, "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/users/1/2_27.jpg"},
  { "pk": 67, "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/users/1/2_27.jpg"}
];

var order_object = arr.findIndex( s => s.pk == 11 ) + 1;

console.log( order_object );
```

Comment: Spectacular! Thank you very much. Vote best for ya :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`[].findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the first index of a matching predicate.

Comment: Thanks for your tip!